# Is there a way to clear conversation history after the end of session

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

My Google Assistant app provides user with sensitive data that shouldn't be visible without two-factor authentication.
Unfortunately everything user and Assistant say to each other is saved and visible after scrolling up inside Assistant app even after end of the session.
Is there any way to turn off conversation saving so it's not visible after end of session?

User can turn off Assistant conversation history saving himself but since app is supposed to be fully secured it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your conversation, you could ask the user to manually delete their history:

```
conv.ask(`Remember to clear your Google Assistant activity!`);

if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
  conv.ask('For instructions on how to clear your activity, please revisit this action from a device with a screen.');
  return;
}

// Create a basic card
conv.ask(new BasicCard({
  text: 'Your Google Assistant stores your past activity to do things like remember your interests and give more personalized responses. You can see or delete your past activity at any time.'
  title: 'Delete your Google Assistant activity.',
  buttons: new Button({
    title: 'Learn how',
    url: 'https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7108295?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en',
  }),
}));
```

Source: https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7108295?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en, https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses, https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data,

Comment: Thank you for the response! Do you think there is any possibility for Google Assistant app to delete its history implicitly, or not store it at all?